# Missing 'HID-Compliant Device/Consumer Control Device'

Tags: windows-server-2003, kvm-switch, hid, dell-poweredge

When I go to use my Server (**Dell PowerEdge T300** running Windows Server 2003 R2), I have to sometimes use our 2 Port USB KMV Switch (**TrendNet TK-209**) to switch from a different computer to my Server. Every now and then when I use the kmv switch, it will be blinking which indicates its waiting for the machine to accept the usb keyboard/mouse (through the KVM of course).

Well it will keep blinking and will never really switch over. When I connect to the Server via RDP it shows in the Device Manager that the *HID-Compliant Consumer Device Control/HID-Compliant Device/HID-Compliant Device have no driver installed* (The icon has a yellow exclamation mark).

If I try to uninstall the driver, it will seem to go on forever (I have let it run for over 30+ hours). Same thing happens if I try to disable it. Same also happens if I use Add/Remove Hardware.

When its not accepting the keyboard/mouse such as I have described, it will also not accept any other USB devices, which makes it impossible to retrieve my daily backup. My current and only fix is to reboot the server. While this does fix the problem it means I can not create/view/edit any purchases. Anyone who is calling in for product support has to then wait, and sales have to wait.

Do you think it could be my KVM switch malfunctioning, or maybe the keyboard/mouse causing the issue?